# Python 2.7 Class How to get a variable from a Mixin and change the variable in Mixin

Tags: python, class, oop, object, mixins

How would I go about using a Mixin to get data that continually changes to flow through my other classes so I can access the data without having to relate to it from an instance of a class within all my classes/objects?

**Example**

```
class DataMixin(object):
  data = {}

  def change_data(self, data=None):
    """
    HERE I AM TRYING TO ASSIGN data TO THE MIXIN ITSELF SO ALL CLASSES
    USING THIS MIXIN RECEIVE THE SAME UPDATED data FIELD
    """
    super(DataMixin, self).data = data


dm = DataMixin()

# EDIT. Moved Below line lower.
# dm.change_data(data={'new': 'data'})


class Class1(DataMixin, object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.data = super(Class1, self).data


class Class2(DataMixin, object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.data = super(Class2, self).data


c1 = Class1()
c2 = Class2()

# EDIT. MOVED TO HERE.
dm.change_data(data={'new': 'data'})

print "c1: {}".format(c1.data)
print "c2: {}".format(c2.data)
```

The above code prints:

> c1: {}
>
> c2: {}

I want it to print:

> c1: {'new': 'data'}
>
> c2: {'new': 'data'}

Is there a way of doing the above using Mixins?
"OR"
Do I need to go about this a better way? Please explain if it should be done a better way.

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

That's because dm is an instance of class DataMixin and c1, c2 cannot inherit data value from instances. If you want c1, c2 inherits the attribute 'data' from parent class DataMixin, you can make function change_data as classmethod like this

```
    @classmethod   
    def change_data(self, data=None):
    """
    HERE I AM TRYING TO ASSIGN data TO THE MIXIN ITSELF SO ALL CLASSES
    USING THIS MIXIN RECEIVE THE SAME UPDATED data FIELD
    """
    self.data = data
```